# Magento 2: Override shipment save controller magento 2 Error

Tags: magento2.3.3

I have to override the Admin shipment save controller. Overridden it in my custom module and it's calling. But when I'm going to create the shipment I'm getting an error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function `validate()` on null for line

```
$validationResult = $this->shipmentValidator->validate($shipment, [QuantityValidator::class]);

<preference for="Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save" />

<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Validation\QuantityValidator;

    Class Save extends \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save implements HttpPostActionInterface
    {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\ShipmentLoader
     */
    protected $shipmentLoader;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator
     */
    protected $labelGenerator;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender
     */
    protected $shipmentSender;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface
     */
    private $shipmentValidator;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\ShipmentLoader $shipmentLoader,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator $labelGenerator,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface $shipmentValidator = null,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $shipmentLoader,
            $labelGenerator,
            $shipmentSender,
            $shipmentValidator ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface::class)
        );
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $formKeyIsValid = $this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest());
        $isPost = $this->getRequest()->isPost();
        if (!$formKeyIsValid || !$isPost) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t save the shipment right now.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/index');
        }

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment');

        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();

        if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\Session::class)->setCommentText($data['comment_text']);
        }

        $isNeedCreateLabel = isset($data['create_shipping_label']) && $data['create_shipping_label'];
        $responseAjax = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();

        try {
            $this->shipmentLoader->setOrderId($this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'));
            $this->shipmentLoader->setShipmentId($this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id'));
            $this->shipmentLoader->setShipment($data);
            $this->shipmentLoader->setTracking($this->getRequest()->getParam('tracking'));
            $shipment = $this->shipmentLoader->load();
            if (!$shipment) {
                return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_FORWARD)->forward('noroute');
            }

            if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
                $shipment->addComment(
                    $data['comment_text'],
                    isset($data['comment_customer_notify']),
                    isset($data['is_visible_on_front'])
                );

                $shipment->setCustomerNote($data['comment_text']);
                $shipment->setCustomerNoteNotify(isset($data['comment_customer_notify']));
            }
            $validationResult = $this->shipmentValidator->validate($shipment, [QuantityValidator::class]);

            if ($validationResult->hasMessages()) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                    __("Shipment Document Validation Error(s):\n" . implode("\n", $validationResult->getMessages()))
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new', ['order_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')]);
            }
            $shipment->register();

            $shipment->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(!empty($data['send_email']));

            if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
                $this->labelGenerator->create($shipment, $this->_request);
                $responseAjax->setOk(true);
            }

            $this->_saveShipment($shipment);

            if (!empty($data['send_email'])) {
                $this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
            }

            $shipmentCreatedMessage = __('The shipment has been created.');
            $labelCreatedMessage = __('You created the shipping label.');

            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                $isNeedCreateLabel ? $shipmentCreatedMessage . ' ' . $labelCreatedMessage : $shipmentCreatedMessage
            );
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\Session::class)->getCommentText(true);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
                $responseAjax->setError(true);
                $responseAjax->setMessage($e->getMessage());
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new', ['order_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
                $responseAjax->setError(true);
                $responseAjax->setMessage(__('An error occurred while creating shipping label.'));
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Cannot save shipment.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new', ['order_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')]);
            }
        }
        if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
            return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setJsonData($responseAjax->toJson());
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $shipment->getOrderId()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with below constructor

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\ShipmentLoader $shipmentLoader,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator $labelGenerator,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface $shipmentValidator,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $shipmentLoader,
        $labelGenerator,
        $shipmentSender,
        $shipmentValidator
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error for shipment validator not form validator

Comment: If you are using preference then there is no need to use constructor

Comment: But I have injected additional class there \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection

Comment: I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: Assign one custom variable and assign object in constructor to it and use that variable in execute method, it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\ShipmentLoader $shipmentLoader,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator $labelGenerator,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface $shipmentValidator,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    $this->shipmentValidator = $shipmentValidator ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface::class);
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $shipmentLoader,
        $labelGenerator,
        $shipmentSender,
        $this->shipmentValidator
    );

}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i try to do by preference, for that need to add admin di.xml

1. adminhtml/di.xml

2. Create custom save.php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Validation\QuantityValidator;

class Save extends \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save
{

```
const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::shipment';

protected $shipmentLoader;


protected $labelGenerator;


protected $shipmentSender;


private $shipmentValidator;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\ShipmentLoader $shipmentLoader
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator $labelGenerator
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender $shipmentSender
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface|null $shipmentValidator
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\ShipmentLoader $shipmentLoader,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator $labelGenerator,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface $shipmentValidator = null
) {
    $this->shipmentLoader = $shipmentLoader;
    $this->labelGenerator = $labelGenerator;
    $this->shipmentSender = $shipmentSender;
    $this->shipmentValidator = $shipmentValidator ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ShipmentValidatorInterface::class);
    parent::__construct($context, $shipmentLoader,$labelGenerator,$shipmentSender, $shipmentValidator );
}

/**
 * Save shipment and order in one transaction
 *
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment $shipment
 * @return \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save
 */
protected function _saveShipment($shipment)
{
    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
    $transaction = $this->_objectManager->create(
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction::class
    );
    $transaction->addObject(
        $shipment
    )->addObject(
        $shipment->getOrder()
    )->save();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Save shipment
 *
 * We can save only new shipment. Existing shipments are not editable
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    $formKeyIsValid = $this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest());
    $isPost = $this->getRequest()->isPost();
    if (!$formKeyIsValid || !$isPost) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t save the shipment right now.'));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/index');
    }

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment');
    if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\Session::class)->setCommentText($data['comment_text']);
    }

    $isNeedCreateLabel = isset($data['create_shipping_label']) && $data['create_shipping_label'];
    $responseAjax = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    try {
        $this->shipmentLoader->setOrderId($this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'));
        $this->shipmentLoader->setShipmentId($this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id'));
        $this->shipmentLoader->setShipment($data);
        $this->shipmentLoader->setTracking($this->getRequest()->getParam('tracking'));
        $shipment = $this->shipmentLoader->load();
        if (!$shipment) {
            return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_FORWARD)->forward('noroute');
        }

        if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
            $shipment->addComment(
                $data['comment_text'],
                isset($data['comment_customer_notify']),
                isset($data['is_visible_on_front'])
            );

            $shipment->setCustomerNote($data['comment_text']);
            $shipment->setCustomerNoteNotify(isset($data['comment_customer_notify']));
        }
        $validationResult = $this->shipmentValidator->validate($shipment, [QuantityValidator::class]);

        if ($validationResult->hasMessages()) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __("Shipment Document Validation Error(s):\n" . implode("\n", $validationResult->getMessages()))
            );
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new', ['order_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')]);
        }
        $shipment->register();

        $shipment->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(!empty($data['send_email']));

        if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
            $this->labelGenerator->create($shipment, $this->_request);
            $responseAjax->setOk(true);
        }
        $this->_saveShipment($shipment);

        if (!empty($data['send_email'])) {
            $this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
        }

        $shipmentCreatedMessage = __('The shipment has been created.');
        $labelCreatedMessage = __('You created the shipping label.');

        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
            $isNeedCreateLabel ? $shipmentCreatedMessage . ' ' . $labelCreatedMessage : $shipmentCreatedMessage
        );
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\Session::class)->getCommentText(true);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
            $responseAjax->setError(true);
            $responseAjax->setMessage($e->getMessage());
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new', ['order_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
        if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
            $responseAjax->setError(true);
            $responseAjax->setMessage(__('An error occurred while creating shipping label.'));
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Cannot save shipment.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new', ['order_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')]);
        }
    }
    if ($isNeedCreateLabel) {
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setJsonData($responseAjax->toJson());
    }

    return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $shipment->getOrderId()]);
}
```

}

Comment: <preference for="Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save"
                  type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save" />